# How to elevate access for user NOT in administrators group and with disabled UAC in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator, uac

When UAC is disabled and you try to perform a task which requires elevated access, you get "Access Denied" for users not in administrators group. However when UAC is enabled, you get an administrator's password prompt, so you can perform an elevated task knowing the admin's password. My question is there ANY way to perform elevated task for users being not in admin's group with disabled UAC?

Comment: The same way you would with UAC enabled.  Use the "run as" capabilities and/or [`runas`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then right-click on your shortcut/executable and there will be a `Run as user...` option.